# How do I stop iteration in Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading a particular excel template in Java using Apache POI. There are some unwanted fields at the bottom (like a small guide) which I need to skip. So I want to stop the iteration whenever POI finds that a row is completely blank and hence the fields at the bottom will be skipped automatically.

I found many ways to handle a blank CELL but my requirement is for a complete row.

Comment: Apache POI supports [two different ways of iterating through rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), which one are you using?

Comment: I was using the same method what Renju showed in his answer. Although I did not think of saving the count. His code worked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will iterate through the cells of a row. it will keep a count for each cell it encounters(cellCount). another couont(nullCount), is incremented only if the cell is blank. if both these counts are equal, row is empty.

```
boolean isEmptyRow = false;
            int cellCount = 0;
            int nullCount = 0;

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cellCount++;
                    Cell cell = (Cell) cellIterator.next();
                    if ((cell == null)
                            || ((cell != null) && (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK))) {
                        nullCount++;
                    }
                }

            if ((cellCount != 0) && (nullCount != 0)
                    && (cellCount == nullCount)) {        //If nullCount & cellCouont are same, Row is empty
                isEmptyRow = true;
            }
```

Comment: I just had one more doubt though. While this will work for me, but right now it is also taking in the first row which is blank. Means it stops after it has encountered the blank row. Is it possible to stop it before that?

Comment: you want to skip the first row of your sheet, which is empty from this check?/ or are you talking about how to avoid reading the first empty row?

Comment: No. Like whenever a blank row comes it takes that row into the record and comes out of the loop.

Comment: No, that will be difficult. The is no way we can identify that the forthcoming row is empty, unless we read it